# Send photo in telegram bot with python

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

With this code, I take a screenshot of the screen and save it in memory
I want to send this photo by bot \

```
import pyscreenshot
def take_pic():
      image = pyscreenshot.grab()
      return image.show()

take_pic()
```

and bot code is :

```
elif number == "??????":
            data = take_pic()
            query.edit_message_text(
                  text=f"{data}",
                  reply_markup=build_keyboard(number_list),
```

my lib is :

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update, bot, message, update
from telegram.ext import ( Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext, InvalidCallbackData, PicklePersistence,filters,BaseFilter )
```

Comment: Hi, please include some additional information in your answer. What is it currently doing? Does it send anything?

Comment: I'm getting information from the bot, but I need to send a screenshot to the bot right now
In other parts, I have no problem sending information, but I have not found the right solution in sending the image yet

Answer (score -1):

`image.show` only returns `True` or `False` because the reutrn type of `pyscreenshot.grab` is `PIL.Image` not regular imag bytes data.
Instead save image in temporary dir and return file path for  further instruction. Try this :

```
img = pyscreenshot.grab()

name = "temp.png"
img.save(name)

bot.send_document(chat_id = chat_id, document = open(name, "rb"))
```

Comment: I use this library to take screenshots and it works fine
There is a problem sending the image to the bot

Comment: Check the type of return value of `image.show` and comment it for ensuring.

Comment: module 'telegram.bot' has no attribute 'send_document'